# How to detect a exchange already bind with a queue or not in rabbitmq with pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

**receiver.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='device', exchange_type='direct')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(
    exchange='device', queue=queue_name, routing_key='abc')

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))
    connection.close()

channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

**sender.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='device', exchange_type='direct')

message = 'Hello World!'
channel.basic_publish(
    exchange='device', routing_key='abc', body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % ('abc', message))
connection.close()
```

I have above `receiver` & `sender` which works well:

```
// first bash session
# python3 receive1.py
 [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] 'abc':b'Hello World!'

// second bash session
# python3 send1.py
 [x] Sent 'abc':'Hello World!'
```

**My problem is:**

If I call `sender.py` first, then call `receiver.py`, the `receiver.py` will not receive the message. I know this because when `sender.py` send the message, the exchange in fact did not bind to any queue, so per rabbitmq's design, it will drop all message without queue bind to exchange.

One solution is to use a named queue, and also declare/bind it in `sender.py`. But if I do this, if last time the consumer did not fetch the message from last sender, this time's new consumer may have chance to receive the old message from last sender.

And for me, the time gap between `receiver` & `sender` to be ready is very small. So I just wonder if possible for `pika` to detect in `sender.py` that the `exchange` already bind with a `queue` or not? If not bind, I will sleep some time then send.

Anyone have suggestion?

Comment: You can to the binding in both sender and receiving. If you use identical parameters, binding as all other configuration operations are idempotent.

Comment: Thanks @LutzHorn, as mentioned in question I not prefer to bind it on both sides.

Comment: Why? This would solve your problem.

Comment: `One solution is to use a named queue, and also declare/bind it in sender.py. But if I do this, if last time the consumer did not fetch the message from last sender, this time's new consumer may have chance to receive the old message from last sender.`, do you think it's possible to happen? I can bare the consumer loss message, but can not bear it receives a message which is old.

Comment: My consumer will close after finish receiving message, then later according user's requirement, a new consumer will be there. But if last time, the old consumer did not fetch the message, then the message will be in queue. Then, if a new consumer start, it will receive the old message, that will make things worse. And, I not insist to know how to detect a exchange bind to a queue or not, just want to get a workable solution for me...

Comment: If the messages must only be consumed by a unique consumer, you will have to create a unique queue for it. Use a transient queue.

Comment: One consumer will back again with same id, when I mention `abc` as binding key, this because I have a pre-communicate to align both sides. So maybe I could set `abc+uuid` for consumers as binding key, then I can bind on both sides, thanks for inspire.